# Jquery, how to disect value from string

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to disect the price from a string that is returned part as a variable

```
price_html: "<span class="price"><span class="amount">£2,196.10</span></span>"
```

Do you know of a jquery function that could disect this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a jQuery object and use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to get the span with class `amount`.

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8jmvY/)**

```
price_html = $('<span class="price"><span class="amount">£2,196.10</span></span>');
price_html.find(".amount").text()
```

or with single statement

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8jmvY/1/)**

```
txt = $('<span class="price"><span class="amount">£2,196.10</span></span>')
        .find(".amount").text()
```

Comment: or just $(price_html).find(".amount").text(); assuming price_html already exists